# Laravel 5 - Get AngularJS controller variable in PHP clause

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

How can I get AngularJS controller variable in PHP clause?

I tried `<?php $user = User::find({{ message.from_id }})?>` but it doesn't work.

`message.blade.php`

```
<div ng-repeat="message in current.messages">

    <?php $user = User::find({{ message.from_id }})?> //not works

    <div>
        <span>User @{{ message.from_id }}</span> //it works
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create angular module that time change angular syntax like this :

```
angular.module("moduleName",[],function($interpolateProvider)    
{
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol("<%");
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol("%>");
})
```

now you can access angular using `<% $scope.VarNm %>` or `<% VarNm %>` in blade.php

and in your case use like

```
 <?php 
    $id = "<%message.from_id%>";
    $user = User::find($id)
 ?>
```

Comment: hmm... but how can I add it? Should I to assign .module using ng-...?

Comment: Yes. when you create your app module for angular that time pass $interpolateProvider and change default syntax.

Comment: I am a beginner in AngularJS. I have a controllers and functions that are already running. I don't know if I understand. In such a case, I have to change all the AngularJS controllers on the AngularJS modules if I want to use `$interpolateProvider`?

Comment: which angular version you have?

Comment: `AngularJs 1.5.8`

Comment: great.! then you can do it when you create your app module set angularjs syntax also

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `@` symbol to inform the Blade rendering engine an expression should remain untouched

```
<div ng-repeat="message in current.messages">
    {{ $user_id = @{{ message.from_id }} }} 
    {{ $user = User::find($user_id) }}
</div>
```

Comment: The php variable would only be assigned once while the page is rendered and can't be reassigned like JavaScript variables